# How to add custom notes to the toolbox in react echarts

Tags: addition, echarts

I want to add a custom notes on the tool box in react echarts.
Using below code i am able to add the text box.

When i click on text box i want to write some text and save it to the load chart. Is there any way to acheive this functionality. Please let me know. Thanks .

```
enter code here brush : {
        toolbox : ['rect'],`enter code here`
        brushLink : [0 , 1, 2 , 3],
        brushType : 'rect',
        brushMode : ['single'],
        outOfBrush: {
            color: '#abc'
        },
        brushStyle: {
            borderWidth: 2,
            color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
        },
        throttleDelay: 300,
    },
    toolbox : {
        show : false,
        feature : {
            brush : {
                    type :  ['rect'],
                    title : {
                        rect : 'Active Brush'
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```